# How can I parse an NSDictionary string representation in python?

Tags: python

Given a dictionary string representation that is not JSON, but very similar:

```
Stuff = {
  randomeString = "hello folks";
  isImportant = 1:
  isSpecial = 0;
  isUnique = 0;
}
```

What's the easiest way to parse this into a python dictionary?

Comment: It would be great if you included some code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use the built-in python library 'ast'. This library has a function called 'literal_eval', which takes a string and returns the python object it represents.

Here is an example:

```py
import ast
s = '{randomeString: "hello folks", isImportant: 1, isSpecial: 0, isUnique: 0}'
d = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(d)
{'randomeString': 'hello folks', 'isImportant': 1, 'isSpecial': 0, 'isUnique': 0}
```

Comment: the string the OP is showing is not a valid Python literal

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can use `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` since your string is not correctly represented and does not form any valid python structure.
From my perspective, I will go with a regex pattern.

This could be a possibility, that works with your example, and can also work for other strings if you do not have nested structures.

```py
import re
dictionary_string="""Stuff = {
                              randomeString = "hello folks";
                              isImportant = 1:
                              isSpecial = 0;
                              isUnique = 0;
                            }"""
def check_numeric(val):
    if val.isnumeric():
        return int(val)
    return val

dictionary = {item[0]: check_numeric(item[1]) for item in lines}
dictionary
dictionary_string = dictionary_string.split(" = ", 1)[1] # this split in Stuff and content 
# find lines, delete extra things and split by "="
lines = [re.sub('\"|;|:', '', i).split(' = ') for i in re.findall("\w.+[:;]", dictionary_string)]
# form your dictionary
dictionary = {item[0]: check_numeric(item[1]) for item in lines}
dictionary
```

output

```py
{'randomeString': 'hello folks',
 'isImportant': 1,
 'isSpecial': 0,
 'isUnique': 0}
```

**Note** that At the moment in the check_numeric, only integer values will be formed. For floating you will need to modify a the function, and add a try/except clause trying to float the value